# Constructing column of time series in R data frame

Tags: r, time-series, apply

Consider

```
x=data.frame(a=c(5,2,7),b=c(3,5,NA),c=c(NA,NA,8))
paste_noNA<-function(x){ts(x[!is.na(x)],frequency=1)}
x$n<-apply(x,1,paste_noNA)
```

On running the last statement, I get the error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, n, value = c(5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 8)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 3
```

The output I want in the new column n in the form of time series is:

```
5,3
2,5
7,8
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you want `n` column of specific class? Or having it as character is fine?

Comment: Specific class. Time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the output of `ts` in a list and apply it to the row.

```
x=data.frame(a=c(5,2,7),b=c(3,5,NA),c=c(NA,NA,8))
paste_noNA<-function(x) list(ts(x[!is.na(x)],frequency=1))
x$n <- apply(x,1,paste_noNA)
x

#  a  b  c    n
#1 5  3 NA 5, 3
#2 2  5 NA 2, 5
#3 7 NA  8 7, 8
```

When you view `n` column separately -

```
x$n
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#Time Series:
#Start = 1 
#End = 2 
#Frequency = 1 
#a b 
#5 3 

#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#Time Series:
#Start = 1 
#End = 2 
#Frequency = 1 
#a b 
#2 5 

#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
#Time Series:
#Start = 1 
#End = 2 
#Frequency = 1 
#a c 
#7 8
```

Comment: It is a list of time-series object. See `class(x$n[[1]][[1]])`. I think downvote has been reversed now.